# python regex breaks with new unicode characters in Mac OS Sonoma filenames

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, macos-sonoma

After updating to Mac OS Sonoma, a [helper script](https://github.com/kortina/dotfiles/blob/master/s3screenshots/s3screenshots.py#L97) I had to upload screenshots to s3 has broken.

Specifically, this:

```py
r = r"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) at (\d{1,2}).(\d{2}\.\d{2}) (AM|PM)\.png"
return re.search(r, filename)
```

Used to match filenames of the pattern:

`/Users/kortina/Desktop/Screenshot 2023-10-03 at 6.57.55 PM.png`

But in Mac OS Sonoma, Screenshots are now named with a unicode character instead of the final space:

`/Users/kortina/Desktop/Screenshot 2023-10-03 at 6.57.55\u202fPM.png`

And the match no longer works.

I don't want to modify the original string, just the regex to get this match to work, but nothing I have tried seems to have worked yet.

Anyone know how to get the regex to match `either` the space `or` the unicode character?

tx in advance...

Comment: So, replace that space with `[ \u202f]`. Or simply use `\s`, it will match any whitespaces.

Comment: Match any spaces, so `\s`, not just " " (\x20).

Answer (score -1):

Ah, `\W` did the trick:

```
r"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) at (\d{1,2}).(\d{2}\.\d{2})\W(AM|PM)\.png"
```

Comment: `\s` is probably better; `\W` matches many non-space characters.